# HTML/CSS - Table Headers on Page Break (Webkit) Laravel PDF

Tags: html, css, laravel, pdf-generation, page-break

Just some background information: I'm using Laravel to render a view, in which it gets converted to a PDF. I am using `barryvdh/laravel-snappy` which utilizes `wkhtmltopdf`. So that actually works great.

But I'm having trouble getting a table in that view to render the way I want it to, which is more of a HTML/CSS issue I would say. This is an invoice, so there is information at the top, like the client address, etc. And then a table that can run multiple pages.

When there are multiple pages, how can I get the table headers to show up on each page? From what I've read, I could normally do it with the `thead` element. But I believe `wkhtmltopdf` uses Webkit under the hood, and so the `thead` doesn't seem to work.

I've read that it was a bug with Chrome / Webkit, but has anyone come up with a work around, or is there a solution nowadays?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share few links with you as a reference.

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2367
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1770#issuecomment-73530576

for me,

```
thead { display: table-header-group }
tfoot { display: table-row-group }
tr { page-break-inside: avoid }
```

this three line of code solved my problem.

If you have a better solution please let me know. Thanks